# Pass file content as build argument in azure devops pipeline docker build task

Tags: bash, azure, shell, docker, azure-devops

I want to pass my file content as build argument in docker build command using --build-arg. I am using following command in terminal and it is working fine

> docker build -t example --build-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat /home/key)"
>   .

but when I am trying same thing in azure devops pipeline docker build task and passing `--build-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat /home/key)"` in arguments box its taking the value as it is i.e, `$(cat /home/key)` and not executing the cat command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is the docker build task's problem. The reason it worked for command line task is probably because when you run the docker build command on your local machine or in the command line task, the command line first will evaluate what is wrapped in "`$()`",and then the value is passed to the docker `ARG`. But for docker build task, it directly invokes docker.exe, so that the expression in "`$()`" cannot be evaluated.

Since you have found the workaround to use the command line task. I suggest you use  command line task instead of docker task.

I also tried what @4c74356b41 suggested. I defined a pipeline variable `key` and put the key's value into this variable and reference this variable in docker build task.

And i worked for me with below when i put `--build-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$(key)"` in the Arguments box.

- Variable
  [image]
- Docker build task

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to declare these variables globally?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either put this value into a variable and reference a variable or use a script step to create a variable out of the contents of the file and reference the variable.

an alternative would be to pass the key to the docker build as a context and inside the build extract that value

Comment: not working in azure devops pipeline.. i am passing --build-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$Key" but instead of taking the value of Key variable, PRIVATE_KEY value is $Key

Comment: --build-arg PRIVATE_KEY=$(key), this is working fine but in this case it is throwing error bad flag syntax: -----END as my Key variable contains SSH private key

Comment: `--buld-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$(key)"`

Comment: I have used that too but in this case it is setting PRIVATE_KEY value as $(key)

Comment: the work around which I found is to use command line step instead of docker build step and then in command line step use command as `docker build -t example --build-arg PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat /home/key)" .`

Comment: nah, this doesn't make sense. you are doing something wrong

Comment: I think there is some problem in azure devops, as I am running the same command from terminal its working fine but when I am passing this command via azure devops pipeline its not working